# SAS EG -How to keep "Program" window open when error in log

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I've just switched to SAS EG from PC-SAS. If I run code from the Program tab, and it creates an error, my view is automatically changed from the Program tab to the Log tab. I'd like to turn this off. Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu Tools-> Options -> Results.  Under managing results section, uncheck "Display SAS log when errors occur."

As a side note, under Tools->Options->SAS Programs->Editor Options you will find a familiar menu for customizing how the editor looks and works.

Comment: Hi Quentin - I've unchecked the box, but it still switches over. Any ideas?

Comment: That's odd. What version of EG are you on?

Comment: I'm on version 6.1

Comment: Agreed, this option does not do what I thought it did.  Surprising.  Perhaps head over to the EG forum at communities.sas.com and see what folks over there say.  Personally, I like the log popup.  But that option sure looks like it should prevent it when unchecked.